# ChartJS Change Axis color

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have MultipleLine Chart and I want to color axis, because it's impossible to see them on my background.

How can I change this option?

I tried zeroLineColor, but it looks like it doesn't exist anymore.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/migration/v3-migration.html - says that now I should use scriptable scale options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code can be used to change color of x-axis in chartjs chart.

```
options: {
scales: {
    y: {
    grid: {
                color: (line) => (line.index === 0 ? 'red' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks.